# copy ssms query result and paste as table in ms teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, ssms

is it possible to copy results from ssms results and copy that results into ms teams chat as table? What I do now is that I copy data from ssms into excel and from excel I copy into MS Teams. But I wonder whether there is some one step shortcut in that. Data from ssms is tab delimited, but data from excel is tab delimited as well. From some reason from excel MS Teams is interpreting the data as table but from ssms it is not.